# Photoswipe automatically initiated

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

*(i'm working on symfony 2.3 for information purpose)*

When loading my page, photoswipe launch itself with my images without being activated by myself. So the screen goes dark, the picture pops up in the middle, I can swipe left and right but I can't see my page at first. The picture just hide everything when opening the page.

[image: example]

I would like to be able to activate it by touching the image just like in the [example](http://photoswipe.com/)

I have set up [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) for my project and followed the doc accordingly regarding the implementation of the [files](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/tree/master/dist)

I initialized my JS this way (note that I didn't add my imgs in the JS, I use a twig loop to add them as they are in my database)

```
var items = [];
var images = $('.fiche-vehicule-image img');

$.each(images, function () {
    items.push({
        src: $(this).attr('src'),
        w: 200,
        h: 200
    });
});
var options = {};
var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
gallery.init();
```

and here is my html where my slideshow (used with bootstrap) is:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="fiche-vehicule-image carousel-inner">
        {% for photo in vehicule.photos %}
            <div class="item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
              <img src="{{ photo.imgLarge }}" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

At last, in order to make that work, I implemented the `pswp` code in the `html.twig` of the carousel code shown above: **Step 2: add PhotoSwipe (.pswp) element to DOM** from the [doc](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html)

Comment: Maybe it launches automatically because your url contains hash value, something like `/#&gid=1&pid=1`? btw, as an alternative, you could just try fancyBox, so much easier to setup and use, see - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/qVNXrZ?editors=1010

Comment: @Janis hi, actually it contains # values yea, It is I guess photoswipe that implement them. Besides isn't that your product fancyBox? It looks nice but its not free as photoswipe is

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry, I should probably have mentioned that.

Comment: @janis That's alright. It just doesn't help me much ^^'

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, you have to manually build custom js file, excluding hash module.

Comment: @Janis I guess that is something to consider yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found an answer to the problem.
I added this line in order to make that work.

```
$('.fiche-vehicule-image').on('click', function () {
```

so the full js is like that

```
$('.fiche-vehicule-image').on('click', function () {
        var items = [];
        var images = $('.fiche-vehicule-image img');

        $.each(images, function () {
            items.push({
                src: $(this).attr('src'),
                w: 200,
                h: 200
            });
        });
        var options = {};
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
        var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        console.log(gallery);
        gallery.init();
    });
```